# Android - Is there a better way to do this layout?

Tags: android-layout

I'm relatively new to android, and wondering if there's a better way to do this layout. I need 4 labels stacked vertically on the left side, with 2 larger-font labels on the right side. If you run this in the emulator it's exactly how I need it, but is there a more preferred way?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/Label1"
        android:text="Label 1: "
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/Label2"
        android:text="Label 2: "
        android:layout_below="@id/Label1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/Label3"
        android:text="Label 3: "
        android:layout_below="@id/Label2"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/Label4"
        android:text="Label 4: "
        android:layout_below="@id/Label3"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Label1">
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/Label6"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Points"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/LabelPoints"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="8.6"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the looks of things you may come a little unstuck if you start to deploy onto different devices with different screen sizes / densities.

If this were my problem, I'd be tempted to use an extra LinearLayout and align these using a weighting. See below..

Hope this helps you, if it's not too late :)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="horizontal">
   <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_weight="1">
       <TextView 
           android:id="@+id/Label1"
           android:text="Label 1: "
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
       <TextView 
           android:id="@+id/Label2"
           android:text="Label 2: "
         android:layout_below="@id/Label1"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
       <TextView 
           android:id="@+id/Label3"
           android:text="Label 3: "
           android:layout_below="@id/Label2"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
       <TextView 
           android:id="@+id/Label4"
           android:text="Label 4: "
           android:layout_below="@id/Label3"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
   </LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Label1">
       <TextView 
           android:id="@+id/Label6"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Points"
           android:textStyle="bold"
           android:textSize="25sp"
           android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
       <TextView 
           android:id="@+id/LabelPoints"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="8.6"
           android:textStyle="bold"
           android:textSize="25sp"
           android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
   </LinearLayout></LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Mark, I think it is not a good way because Android docs refers that relative is more efficient. You can find it here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html

> "A RelativeLayout is a very powerful utility for designing a user
>   interface because it can eliminate nested view groups and keep your
>   layout hierarchy flat, which improves performance."

Comment: It'll be fine for small cases - it's not like he's drawing a table structure out of LinearLayouts

Answer (score 0):

it can do by using TableLayout,too. so, you can add your labels in a row (TableRow). hopefully, it useful for you :-)